# add a class to the item after automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for jQuery code that in case I click on div with id `group`, adds a class to the one right before.

```
<div class="contact-form-conditional">
  <div id="group-805" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
  <div id="group-806" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
  <div id="group-807" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
  <div id="group-808" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
  <div id="group-809" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
  <div id="group-810" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"></div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery('.wpcf7-form').on('click', function() {
  if (jQuery('#group-807').hasClass("focused")) {
    jQuery('#group-806').removeClass("focused");
  } else {
    jQuery('#group-807').addClass("focused");
    jQuery('#group-807').addClass("hereAgain");
  }    
});
```

However this only adds a class to the one just clicked. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: instead if `jQuery` you could simply write `$`. i.e. `$('.wpcf7-form')`

Comment: Your logic seems completely at odds with your description of the issue. That said, you can use the class `focused` class and then `prev()` to do what you need: `$('.wpcf7cf-hidden.focused').prev().addClass('focused')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the class and remove the existing class `focused` and add to the previous one.

```js
$('.wpcf7cf-hidden').on('click',function(){
$(".wpcf7cf-hidden").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("focused");
})
  $(this).prev().addClass('focused');
})
```

```css
.focused {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-form-conditional">
    <div id="group-805" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">1</div>
    <div id="group-806" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">2</div>
    <div id="group-807" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">3</div>
    <div id="group-808" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">4</div>
    <div id="group-809" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">5</div>
    <div id="group-810" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was looking for this, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

**I think you are trying to add class to prev div from current div**

**HTML code**

```
<div class="contact-form-conditional">
    <div id="group-805" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">1</div>
    <div id="group-806" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">2</div>
    <div id="group-807" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">3</div>
    <div id="group-808" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">4</div>
    <div id="group-809" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">5</div>
    <div id="group-810" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden divClass">6</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.divClass',function(){
$(".divClass").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("focused");
})
$(this).prev().addClass('focused');
})
</script>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe the solution of Sumodh Nair is better, but thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

`$('.contact-form-conditional .wpcf7cf-hidden').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().toggleClass('focused')
})`

It selects previous element and toggles `focused` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe the solution of Sumodh Nair is better, but thanks again